# Review: answer marked as high quality?

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

When reviewing I was confronted with the following question and should judge the given answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10759491

> This is a boolean expression, not an assignment.
>
> ```
>   (&result)->_array[i][j] == 0; //Reset result's array.
> ```

That answer is marked as a "high quality answer" which IMHO is completely wrong. The answer does give a vague hint and does not solve the problem.

How can one object to the quality of those answers?

Answer (score 4):

1. I think you misunderstood that answer, which is talking about:

   > See, this line of your code was wrong.

   And not:

   > Try this instead.
2. Whatever, an answer isn't correct shouldn't be flagged as Very Low Quality. See the comment of this declined flag of mine for more details (yeah, show it again...):

   [image: My declined flag]

Comment: As an aside, the question should be closed and deleted.